# CSS animation does not work in IE11, Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I did the animation to rotate around a button, I do not know the tags so well, so I'll probably have many errors in my codes: '(

What annoys me today is that it is not rotating in IE11, I tested in Windows 7 and Windows 10, any browser opens normally, until Edge performs as programmed, except IE11,

The URL of the page in question is http://hb1virtual.com.br/Grafica/

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?
(there will be many errors, but this one especially, laughs)
HTML

```css
.menu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 340px;
 height: 340px;
 margin-left:-170px;
 margin-top:-170px;
}
.marquee{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 340px;
 height: 340px;
 animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
.marquee:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.menuse {
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuse:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd {
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 170px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie {
 margin-top: 170px;
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid {
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 170px;
 margin-left: 170px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menulogo {
 float: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: 224px;
 height: 224px;
 margin-top: 59px;
 margin-left: 61px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: url('../images/logosombra.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="marquee">
<div class="menuse"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menusd"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menuie"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menuid"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

Comment: Please change your title to English…?

Comment: Excuse me. I am Brazilian and forgot to write in English in the title.

Answer (score 0):

There are some CSS mistakes in your animation code.

I try to add a new css code segment and try to apply it on your web page to make it work for IE 11.

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    
   <style>
.menu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 340px;
 height: 340px;
 margin-left:-170px;
 margin-top:-170px;
}
.marquee{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 340px;
 height: 340px;
 animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
   animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
.marquee:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.menuse {
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuse:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd {
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 170px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie {
 margin-top: 170px;
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid {
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 170px;
 margin-left: 170px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04hover.png') no-repeat;
}
.menulogo {
 float: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: 224px;
 height: 224px;
 margin-top: 59px;
 margin-left: 61px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: url('../images/logosombra.png') no-repeat;
}



.clockwise {
    -webkit-animation: clockwiseSpin 10s infinite linear;
    animation: clockwiseSpin 10s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes clockwiseSpin {
 0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);}
    
}@keyframes clockwiseSpin {
 0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);} 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
<div class="clockwise">
<div class="menuse"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menusd"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menuie"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
<div class="menuid"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/botton.png"></a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Further, you can try to check the code and try to modify it in your site.

You can refer the example below.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/devools/zsjfuvxm/2)

Comment: http://hb1virtual.com.br/Grafica/ < my code
http://hb1virtual.com.br/Grafic/teste.html < your code

Unfortunately here it still does not rotate in my IE, tried local and remote, and still changed the axis of rotation, but I have hope, thanks even for sending your code, any other suggestions? Thankful.

Comment: I try to make a test on various OS and find that this code works on most of the OS except Windows 7. So I suggest you to make a test with any other OS. I can see that buttons changed the axis of rotation. But if you see your original code than it is also there. so it may be because of your CSS. you can check it. If possible than try to post the actual code here. it may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score -5):

First, you should change your Title from Portuguese to English.

Second, You can always inject code into your html, blocking IE users from seeing your website, redirecting them to download another browser.

Nobody uses IE anyway... It's not solving the problem, it's avoiding the question, but it's a solution.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexandre. Unfortunately, in Brazil, many bank sites still require the use of the dinosaur (ie), and the government of our country uses only it in their government computers, as I intend to have these places have access to the site, I will give preference for compatibility, in last if I will do what you told me.